# Drupal print if single checkbox field is checked

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I'd like to print something like "yes, checked" if a cck single checkbox is checked.
The single on/off checkbox has allowed values of no and yes.

checkbox info is -

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" checked="checked" value="yes"
    id="edit-field-billing-terms-value" name="field_billing_terms[value]">
```

I'm trying, and failing with modifications of this code -

```
<?php
  $node->field_billing_terms[value] . '<br />';
    if($node->field_billing_terms[value] == 'yes' ) {
      print "yes, checked";
    }
?>
```

Can someone give me some pointers where I'm going wrong? More info can be provided if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields are normally in a zero based array when attached to the node object, this should fix your problem:

```
$node->field_billing_terms[0]['value'] . '<br />';
if($node->field_billing_terms[0]['value'] == 'yes' ) {
  print "yes, checked";
}
```

Comment: Wow, That was fast! Thanks a ton! Works!